# What are the some of the special usecases of general purpose registers

Tags: assembly, x86

Sometimes general purpose registers are used for some specific reasons. For example `EAX` is used as an accumulator and to store return values, `ECX` is used as a counter, `ESI` and `EDI` are used to store the src and dst address, respectively. similarly, `ESP` and `EBP`.

Is there any specific use case for`EBX` register? and Is there anything else that I have missed special use cases of general purpose registers?

Comment: The reason why some instructions use only specific registers is rather historical. It used to be that way that if you didn't have enough bits in instruction to specify a register, and you didin't want your instruction format to become too complex, you created an instruction (using just a single opcode) that had its registers hardcoded. This means: if you want to find out more about it, dig up some old datasheets with descriptions of previous Intel processors.

Answer (score 2):

> EBX: The Base Register
>
> In 16-bit mode, the base register, EBX, acts as a general-purpose pointer. Besides the specialized ESI, EDI, and EBP registers, it is the only general-purpose register that can appear in a square-bracket memory access (For example, MOV [BX], AX). In the 32-bit world, however, any register may serve as a memory offset, so the base register is no longer special.
>
> The base register gets its name from the XLAT instruction. XLAT looks up a value in a table using AL as the index and EBX as the base. XLAT is equivalent to MOV AL, [BX+AL], which is sometimes useful if you need to replace one 8-bit value with another from a table (Think of color look-up).
>
> So, of all the general-purpose registers, EBX is the only register without an important dedicated purpose. It is a good place to store an extra pointer or calculation step, but not much more.

(**quoted** ) the whole source :
[The Art of Picking Intel Registers](http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html)